# Are Tango Project sensors ideal to identify body parts (like legs) in indoor environments?

Tags: sensors, google-project-tango, tango

I'm interested to develop an AR app using a Tango Project cellphone that would be able to identify body parts, like legs, and project some 3D objects on the identified parts. My concern now is if the sensors in Project Tango cellphones are ideal for this and what features I should be starting with. I appreciate any guide.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some research papers on **human body segmentation** / **skeleton tracking** using RGB image + depth map, some only use the RGB image.

I recommend you [this tutorial on Human Body Recognion and Tracking](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/Publications/2016/OB16a/oliveira16icra.pdf) which includes the following interesting reference:

> *Real-Time Human Pose Recognition in Parts from a Single Depth Image*,
>   J. Shotton, A. Fitzgibbon, M. Cook, T. Sharp, M. Finocchio, R. Moore,
>   A. Kipman, and A. Blake, Proc. IEEE Conf. Computer Vision and Pattern
>   Recognition, 2011

These works were performs with Kinect-like sensors, which have a higher resolution depth map than the Google Tango devices, so unfortunately I cannot tell for certain the results will be as good with a Google Tango device.

Comment: Thank you very much, Vincent. I will look into them and check the results.